# Magento addAttribute duplicate after delete of core_resource entry

Tags: magento, adminhtml

if i delete core_resource.code='my_setup_module' and rerun magento, everything in my sql/ files duplicates.  is there a way to prevent this? (that's it.  the rest of this is buffer material so stackoverflow let's me submit.)

example sql file

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'googlemerchant_category', array(
    'label'         => 'Google Merchant category',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'input'         => 'multiselect',
    'backend'       => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'group'         => 'Google Merchant',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'position'      => 2,
    'option' =>
        array (
            'value' =>
                array(
                    'option1' => array('Apparel & Accessories > Clothing'),
                    'option2' => array('Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear > Sweatshirts'),
                    'option3' => array('Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Underwear & Socks > Socks'),
                    'option4' => array('Apparel & Accessories > Clothing Accessories'),
                    'option5' => array('Apparel & Accessories > Shoes'),
                    'option6' => array('Apparel & Accessories > Shoes > Athletic Shoes'),
                    'option7' => array('Apparel & Accessories > Shoes > Sneakers'),
                    'option8' => array('Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Hats'),
                    'option9' => array('Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Shorts'),
                    'option10' => array('Apparel & Accessories > Handbags'),
                    'option11' => array('Food, Beverages & Tobacco > Food Items'),
                    'option12' => array('Hardware > Flooring'),
                    'option13' => array('Health & Beauty > Health Care > Physical Therapy Equipment'),
                    'option14' => array('Media'),
                    'option15' => array('Media > Books'),
                    'option16' => array('Media > Books > Non-Fiction'),
                    'option17' => array('Media > Books > Non-Fiction > Body, Mind & Spirit Books'),
                    'option18' => array('Media > Books > Non-Fiction > Health & Fitness Books'),
                    'option19' => array('Media > DVDs & Videos'),
                    'option20' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness'),
                    'option21' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Abdominal Equipment'),
                    'option22' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Exercise Balls'),
                    'option23' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Exercise Bands'),
                    'option24' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Foam Rollers'),
                    'option25' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Free Weight Bars'),
                    'option26' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Gym Mats'),
                    'option27' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Jump Ropes'),
                    'option28' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Medicine Balls'),
                    'option29' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Stopwatches'),
                    'option30' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Weight Benches'),
                    'option31' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Weightlifting Belts'),
                    'option32' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Weightlifting Gloves'),
                    'option33' => array('Sporting Goods > Exercise & Fitness > Weightlifting Machine Accessories'),
                    'option34' => array('Sporting Goods > Gymnastics > Gymnastics Bars'),
                    'option35' => array('Sporting Goods > Gymnastics > Gymnastics Mats'),
                    'option36' => array('Sporting Goods > Gymnastics > Gymnastics Rings'),
                    'option37' => array('Sporting Goods > Jumping')
                )
        )
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will obviously duplicate as when you delete core_resource entry of your module, it will re-run whole setup and find your setup file again to execute.

Remember, Magento only knows if a module's setup is run or not by core_resource table. So, if it doesn't find your module entry over there, it will simply run your setup file regardless of whether it's already run or not.

Comment: is there any way to "dummy proof" this?

Comment: Please check this article: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources/

Comment: thanks.  I guess if I really wanted I could perform some SQL 'select' statements and go from there.  There is problem we have where the information duplicated.  I know about core_resource but wanted to make certain there wasn't an edge case I was missing.

Thanks.